# elisp Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p error

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the text below (with actual tabs in instead of \t) and I need to get to just after the tab after "Description" and grab all the text until the end of the buffer.

```
key1\tval1      
key2\tval2
key3\tval3      
Description\tlots and lots and lots and lots and lots lots 
and lots and lots and lots and lots lots and lots and lots and 
lots and lots lots and lots and lots and lots and lots lots and 

lots lots and lots and lots and lots and lots lots and lots lots 

and lots and lots and lots and lots lots and lots lots and lots 

and lots and lots and lots lots and lots lots and lots and lots 
and lots and lots lots and lots lots and lots and lots and lots 
and lots lots and lots lots and lots and lots and lots and lots
```

Here is the lisp function:

```
(defun find-description()
  (interactive) 
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (when (re-search-forward "Description\t")
    (setq myStr (buffer-substring (point) (end-of-line)))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert "\n\n\ndescription=")
    (insert myStr)
   )
)
```

And this fails on the (setq line with error:

```
Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil
```

I assumed that after the regex search that the point will be just after Description\t.  So why doesn't setting the variable work?

Comment: `end-of-line` *moves* to the end of line rather than returning it.  You want to use `line-end-position` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `end-of-line` is not a marker or position, so attempting to use that in `buffer-substring` is what causes the error message.  The easy fix is to get the buffer position after moving to end of line;

```
(let ((beg (point))
  (end-of-line)
  (setq myStr (buffer-substring beg (point)) )
```

Notice also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974319/874188 which points out `line-end-position` as an even simpler fix for this.

You could also refactor this to avoid the temporary variable e.g. by searching for `"Description\t\([^\n]*\)"` and pulling out the matching substring, but I suppose either way is fine.

By the by, examining the backtrace you would get by setting `debug-on-error` to a true value would quickly have revealed the reason for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using the backtrace - will investigate that.

Comment: Also BTW, a library function which uses regex search should wrap it in [`save-match-data`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Match-Data.html).